# Problems to clone a fetch object into an undefined object in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this trouble, i've defined a poke object and i try to clone to this an object thats give me this link https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ but i only get a promise fullfiled with the object i search for, no the object itself in the poke object.
Here's the code:

```
let poke = fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
console.log(poke);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: i don't understand that solution, srry.

Comment: why do you want to clone an API response? It will be a new object each time anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add await before, smth like

```
async () => {
  let poke = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  console.log(poke);
}
```

fetch is async, so you need to wait response, via await or then

```
  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))).then(data => {console.log(data)});
```